# Having problem installing jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

Im trying to install jupyter notebook,
I updated my Python version using this command:
pip3 install --upgrade pip
Then I wrote this in my CMD:
python -m pip install jupyter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcEHQ.png)
I also wrote this:
pip3 install jupyter

And every time I try to start the jupyter notebook the operating system does not find it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMdYB.png)

why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this documentation for reference https://jupyter.org/install.
To be able to launch jupyter notebook, I think you have to install Notebook using command 'pip install notebook' then type 'jupyter notebook' to start the Notebook. I hope this helps. If not, please provide more details to this matter.

PS: I assume that you also have Python in your Home environment so that the installation of any packages works properly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your operating system is unable to locate your module. You can resolve this issue by adding the path of your module to the environment variable. First, copy the path where your Jupyter Notebook is installed, and then add this path to the environment variable.

To do this, follow these steps:

1. Search for "Edit the System environment variable" in the search bar.
2. Navigate to "Environment Variables" under the "System Properties"
   window.
3. In the "System Variables" section, click on "New" to add a   new
   system variable.
4. Enter the name and path of your Jupyter Notebook    installation
   directory.
5. Click "OK" to save the changes.